# getting exact match for list of columns name from files

Tags: regex, python-3.7

I have created a script where I read from a list of column names that need to be deleted and specified a list of directories to scan for the sql and python files to find  a match using the python - but I used the python IN clause which returns not a specific match.  Would like some assistance to do this using regex.

The column names in the sql and pythonfiles could start AND end with either a space, a single quote, or a comma.   Appreciate it in advance.

Here is my code - I marked the two lines of code that need to be changed to regex

```
    import glob        

    # read the list of column_fields_to_delete.txt into a list
    columns_to_delete_file = 'column_fields_to_delete.txt'
    
    with open(columns_to_delete_file) as f:
        columns_file = [line.strip() for line in f]
    

    delete_columns_list = [column for column in columns_file]
    
    # specify directories from which to scan all sql files from
    directories = ['/users/xx/sql/**/*.sql',
                   '/users/xx/Python/**/*.py']
    
    output_lines = list()
    
    for directory in directories:
       for file in glob.glob(directory, recursive=True):
        try:
            with open(file, 'r') as f:
                contents = f.read()
            exception_columns = list()
            for column_name in delete_columns_list:
                if column_name in contents.upper():        #--------- this needs to be changed to re.findall()
                   exception_columns.append(column_name)   #--------- this may need to be modified as well 
    
            if exception_columns:
                print(f"{file} file contains exception columns {exception_columns}\n\n")
            
        except:
        pass
```

The expected output is to print each sql or python file that references any of the columns from the delete_column_list, followed by the actual columns with the exact matches.

Comment: Did you try python's `re` module?

Comment: Yes, but the regex thing is quite confusing. Just need some help on how to  put the “the column names  could start AND end with either a space, a single quote, or a comma.” into a regex statement.

Comment: Also, can the column names **contain any special characters**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex that you can use to achieve your purpose is:

```
r'[\s,\'"]' + column_name + r'[\s,\'"]'
```

along with `re.findAll`.

I have made few adjustments to your code. The code looks somewhat like below:

```py
import glob
import re        

# read the list of column_fields_to_delete.txt into a list
columns_to_delete_file = 'column_fields_to_delete.txt'

with open(columns_to_delete_file) as f:
    columns_file = [line.strip() for line in f]

delete_columns_list = [column for column in columns_file]

# specify directory from which to scan all sql files from
directory = '/users/xx/sql/**/*.sql'

output_lines = list()

for file in glob.glob(directory, recursive=True):
    try:
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            contents = f.read()
        exception_columns = list()
        for column_name in delete_columns_list:
            matches = re.findall(r'[\s,\'"]' + column_name + r'[\s,\'"]', contents, re.IGNORECASE)
            if matches:
                exception_columns.append(column_name)

        if exception_columns:
            print(f"{file} file contains exception columns {exception_columns}\n\n")
    except:
        pass
```

**Explanation for the above code modifications:**

- The regex pattern that I used matches any column name that is surrounded by whitespace, commas, single quotes, or double quotes.
- The `re.findall()` function returns a list of all matches in the contents of the file.
- I have also used `re.IGNORECASE` flag to make the search case-insensitive. You can change that as per your requirement.
- If there are any matches:

  - append the column name to the exception_columns list, and then print the filename and the list of exception columns.

Comment: Thank you so much!   I will try this out in the morning.   Really like your explanation and the use of re.findall()  is very helpful.   And regarding your question - the column names that we use  only have one special character - the underscore  (e.g.,  first_and_last_name) which is pretty much standard in most DBMS.  And the re.IGNORECASE flag is  a very good too as well.   Kudos!

Comment: `_` is usually not included in special characters. But if there is any other special characters you can use **[`re.escape`](https://learnbyexample.github.io/py_regular_expressions/escaping-metacharacters.html#reescape)**

Comment: Thanks!   I have saved my own post to keep these info handy.  Don’t use regex a lot but they sure can be very useful.